# Applications of diffeological spaces to ordinary differential geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, generalized-smooth-spaces, diffeology

Recently I've been learning more about differential geometry, and I came upon the notion of a [diffeological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeology), which encompasses a number of already known extensions of smooth manifolds or related notions, like Banach and Frechét manifolds, complex and analytic manifolds, but also includes a number of other constructions (like quotients and mapping spaces), making the category of diffeological spaces quite well-behaved and nice to work with.

However, I couldn't find much information about applications of diffeology to "ordinary" differential geometry, and would love to hear about some results in this vein. Have diffeological spaces been used to obtain meaningful results about ordinary manifolds (smooth, complex, analytic, p-adic, etc.), specially for cases in which there's no known proof that does not use diffeology?

One example would be something like using the de Rham cohomology of (or other constructions involving) the diffeological space of diffeomorphisms/symplectomorphisms/smooth maps to prove results about ordinary manifolds.

Comment: (P.S. This question is a bit similar to the question [Nice application of generalized smooth spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55128), which asks how generalised smooth spaces (like diffeological spaces) can aid in _simplifying_ proofs of _already known_ facts in differential geometry.)

Comment: Also a nice survey of diffeological spaces is _An Introduction to Diffeology_, by Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour, available [here](http://math.huji.ac.il/~piz/documents/AITD.pdf). There's also a textbook by the same author, [here](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/08bIgfV5NT8F8oBo-Ipqoz1kg#Diffeology)

Comment: I am not aware of much in the way of results.  My impression is that diffeological spaces are primarily motivated by creating a nice categorical framework for common "spaces of manifolds" arguments, but most theorems the differential geometry community are interested in have little categorical flavour of that sort.  I would imagine the most fruitful area of overlap would be the TQFT and cobordism category areas, but those again are more dominated by algebraic topology style arguments.

Comment: Similar to other areas of mathematics, people tend to generalize the classical results and constructions in such a way when they restrict themselves to the ordinary setting they recover the classical results and constructions. Analogous to the situation in that we move from Euclidean spaces to manifolds.

Comment: In this way, it seems we should not expect diffeology to do something extraordinary in ordinary differential geometry. So it would be better to ask what are applications (or capabilities) of diffeological spaces to beyond ordinary differential geometry, where the classical framework cannot go further, such as singular spaces like orbifolds, function spaces, foliations, groupoids, etc.

Comment: @ARA I think situations where moving to more general objects while still recovering the classical results often(-ish?) end up also giving some applications to the classical objects, like how one can use schemes to prove new results about algebraic varieties, or how derived stuff (in the sense of DAG) can help to prove things about classical objects.

Comment: One example I could imagine this kind of situation happening for diffeological spaces would be applying general constructions for diffeological spaces to more general spaces attached to ordinary manifolds (so things like studying the diffeological de Rham cohomology of function spaces, quotients, etc. of manifolds to prove stuff about the manifolds in question (i'm not sure if this particular example makes sense though, as I'm still not really familiar with diffeological spaces))

Comment: (in any case though I'd be completely happy if diffeological spaces turned out to have zero extraordinary applications to ordinary differential geometry; just the fact that they allow so many constructions to be made in a natural way and which are otherwise impossible already makes them really great in my opinion =) I'm really just curious about whether, in addition to that, they _also_ provide some nice applications, like in the case of schemes vs. varieties)

Comment: @Emily, Great! It seems you are seeking situations like "arXiv:2102.10091"?

Comment: @ARA That's a great example, thanks for telling me about it! Do you know any other situations like that one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you can find some applications of diffeology "merely" in differential geometry of manifolds in the following list (I am not sure this list is exhaustive):

- **The (internal) tangent space of the diffeomorphism group of a compact manifold is the space of its vector fields**, See [Hector G. Géométrie et topologie des espaces difféologiques. Analysis and geometry in foliated manifolds (Santiago de Compostela, 1994). 1995 Nov 17:55-80.](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Fec7DwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA55&dq=Hector%20G.%20G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie%20et%20topologie%20des%20espaces%20diff%C3%A9ologiques.%20Analysis%20and%20geometry%20in%20foliated%20manifolds%20(Santiago%20de%20Compostela,%201994).%201995%20Nov%2017:55-80.&ots=dErQjDNNko&sig=dSc43L8CJ8ZTDCrPBBJnUy0VSNQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)**or**
  [[J.D. Christensen, E. Wu, Tangent spaces and tangent bundles for diffeological spaces, Cah. Topol. G'{e}om. Diff'{e}r. Cat'{e}g. 57(1) (2016), 3-50.]](http://cahierstgdc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ChristensenWu.pdf).
- **The diffeomorphism group of a Lie foliation**, See [Hector G, Macías-Virgós E, Sotelo-Armesto A. The diffeomorphism group of a Lie foliation. InAnnales de l'Institut Fourier 2011 (Vol. 61, No. 1, pp. 365-378).](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.2605.pdf)
- **De Rham cohomology of diffeological spaces and foliations**, See [Hector G, Macías-Virgós E, Sanmartín-Carbón E. De Rham cohomology of diffeological spaces and foliations. Indagationes Mathematicae. 2011 Aug 1;21(3-4):212-20.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357711000140)
- **The basic de Rham complex of a singular foliation**, See [Miyamoto D. The Basic de Rham Complex of a Singular Foliation. International Mathematics Research Notices.](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article-abstract/2023/8/6364/6540673?redirectedFrom=PDF)
- **Basic forms and orbit spaces: a diffeological approach**, See [Karshon Y, Watts J. Basic forms and orbit spaces: a diffeological approach. SIGMA. Symmetry, Integrability and Geometry: Methods and Applications. 2016 Mar 8;12:026.](https://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2016/026/sigma16-026.pdf)
- **The orientation-preserving diffeomorphism group of $\mathbb{S}^2$ deforms to SO (3) smoothly**, See [Li J, Watts JA. The orientation-preserving diffeomorphism group of $\mathbb{S}^2$ deforms to SO (3) smoothly. Transformation Groups. 2011 Jun;16(2):537-53.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00031-011-9130-0)
- **Smooth Lie group actions are parametrized diffeological subgroups**, See [Iglesias-Zemmour P, Karshon Y. Smooth Lie group actions are parametrized diffeological subgroups. Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society. 2012 Feb;140(2):731-9.](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-02/S0002-9939-2011-11301-7/S0002-9939-2011-11301-7.pdf)
- **Differential forms on manifolds with boundary and corners** See [Gürer S, Iglesias-Zemmour P. Differential forms on manifolds with boundary and corners. Indagationes Mathematicae. 2019 Sep 1;30(5):920-9.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0019357719300436)
- **The Geodesics of the 2-Torus** See [here](http://math.huji.ac.il/%7Epiz/documents/DBlog-Rmk-TGOT2T.pdf).
- **Every symplectic manifold is a (linear) coadjoint orbit** See [Donato P, Iglesias-Zemmour P. Every symplectic manifold is a (linear) coadjoint orbit. Canadian Mathematical Bulletin. 2022 Jun;65(2):345-60.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/abs/every-symplectic-manifold-is-a-linear-coadjoint-orbit/60EEA4D0397E72FAE554ADEE9EC800B0)
- **De Rham cohomology for the complement of a (dense) irrational flow on the torus** See [this MO post and Patrick I-Z's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427637/can-one-make-sense-of-de-rham-cohomology-for-the-complement-of-a-dense-irratio/449827#449827)

I also believe that even if one is interested in smooth manifolds, it is much easier and conceptual (or perhaps natural) to define "smooth" manifolds through diffeological spaces, just like the definition of topological manifolds. Actually, we can say that a smooth manifold is a diffeological space that is locally Euclidean: every point in the space has an open neighborhood (with respect to the D-topology) which is diffeomorphic to an open subset of a fixed Euclidean space. After that, one can add Hausdorfness and second-countability requirements, if needed. In this situation, there is no need to talk about the smooth compatibility of charts, because it is automatically verified. Notice that diffeological spaces are an extension of Euclidean spaces in the first place.

Comment: ODG is "ordinary differential geometry"?

Comment: Yes, I just edited it.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, and what you say about manifolds can be extended to orbifolds which are diffeological spaces locally diffeomorphic at each point to some quotient ${\mathbf R}^n/G$ where $G$ is a finite linear group and may change from point to point. It can be said also to "quaisfolds" which are defined as locally diffeomorphic to ${\mathbf R}^n/G$ with $G$ a countable subgroup of the affine group $\mathrm{Aff}({\mathbf R}^n)$. It follows the general process of "Modeling diffeological spaces" Chapter 4 in the book. [To be continued]

Comment: [Follow up] For these two example look for "Noncommutative geometry and diffeology: The case of orbifolds" and "Quasifolds, Diffeology and Noncommutative Geometry".

Comment: In particular, diffeology provides a simple way for someone who wants to learn such spaces.

Answer (score 10):

I would add to the previous list of "applications" of diffeology in ordinary differential geometry the theorem about *Homotopic invariance of De Rham cohomology* (§6.88 of [Diffeology](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/08bIgfV5NT8F8oBo-Ipqoz1kg#Diffeology)). In brief:

**Theorem**: *Let $X$ and $X'$ be two diffeological spaces. Let $f_0$ and $f_1$ be two homotopic smooth maps from $X'$ to $X$. Let $\alpha$ be a closed $k$-form on $X$, then $f_1^*(\alpha)$ is cohomologous to $f_0^*(\alpha)$.*

The diffeological proof uses the Chain-Homotopy operator (§6.83 op.cit)

$$
K : \Omega^p(X) \to \Omega^{p-1} (\mathrm{Paths}(X)), \ \text{that satisfies} \ K \circ d + d \circ K = \hat 1^* - \hat 0^*,
$$

where $\Omega^p$ denotes the space of differential $p$-forms, $\mathrm{Paths}(X) = C^\infty({\mathbf R}, X)$ is the set of smooth paths in $X$, and for all $\gamma \in \mathrm{Paths}(X)$, $\hat t(\gamma) = \gamma(t)$.

**Proof**: For all $x' \in X'$ let:

$$
\phi(x') = [s \mapsto f_s(x')],  \ \text{then} \ \phi \in C^\infty\big( X',\mathrm{Paths}(X)\big).
$$

Apply $\phi^*$ to the identity above satisfied by $K$, evaluated on $\alpha$
$$
\phi^*[K d\alpha + d K\alpha] = \phi^*(\hat 1^*(\alpha)) - \phi^*(\hat 0^*(\alpha)).
$$
Since $d\alpha = 0$ and $\hat t \circ \phi = f_t$ we get
$$
f_1^*(\alpha) = f_0^*(\alpha) + d\beta, \ \text{with} \  \beta = \phi^*(K\alpha).
$$
Therefore, $f_1^*(\mathrm{class}(\alpha)) = f_0^*(\mathrm{class}(\alpha))$. $\square$

This general theorem applies in particular for $X$ and $X'$ manifolds since the category of manifolds is a full subcategory of diffeological spaces. This is an example where diffeology helps in a proof of a classical differential geometry theorem, using a shortcut thru a space which is not a manifold: the space $\mathrm{Paths}(X)$. And as we see it was important to have a good definition of differential forms on every diffeological space, whatever they are.

By the way the Chain-Homotopy operator is used also in *Symplectic Diffeology* for the definition and the generalisation of [The Moment Map in Diffeology](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-207-972). You will find in that Memoir a few of examples of application of diffeology in symplectic geometry.

---

**Addendum**: We maintain a Monthly Global Seminar in Diffeology, all informations on http://diffeology.net

Comment: Nice *answer*..

Comment: Wow, this is very cool! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Well, the space of smooth infinite paths _is_ a manifold, just a rather nasty infinite-dimensional one :-)